# Laravel is displaying error message before form submit

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-validation

in my last question i was asking for help with single error message displaying after incorrectly filled form instead of error for every incorrect input. They were wery helpfull and I received this piece of code:

```
          @if ($errors)
              <span class='help-block'>
                  <strong>{{ "There are errors" }}</strong>
              </span>
          @endif
```

and the second answer was

```
 @if (!empty($errors))
 <span class='help-block'>
     <strong>{{ "Some input field is not properly filled" }}</strong>
 </span>
 @endif
```

I thought that the  above will be displayed  only after form submiting and if Laravel will find  any errors. The problem is that it's always displaying error message like in the screenshot under:
[image]
Does anyone knows the solution? Many Thanks.

Comment: Try outputting the errors with `{{ $errors }}`. You might have to do something like `!empty($errors)`, because it could just be an empty array.

Comment: tried before, but without any effect

Comment: Post the form your are submitting along with the controller method that handles it. What happens when you simply refresh the page the form is on? The error messages should clear if they are not being reflashed to the session somehow.

Comment: So you want to show the errors only have the submit correct?

Comment: Thus please show the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$errors` variable is always set. It's a [message bag](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html) that might or might not contain messages.

You could check like this:

```
 @if ($errors->count() > 0)
 <span class='help-block'>
     <strong>{{ "Some input field is not properly filled" }}</strong>
 </span>
 @endif
```

`@if (!$errors->isEmpty())` should also work.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood it correctly, you want to show the success or error message only after submitting your form.

If that is the case following should work:

You need to add / change following in your Controller function:

```
$request->session()->flash('success', 'Success!');
return redirect()->route("yourstuff.index");
```

In your blade.php you return that session with it message like this

```
    @if (session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if (session('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('error') }}
        </div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, i received two good answers but i choosed simplier one. 
In order to return single error I used the code proposed by user:

> devk

```
    @if ($errors->count() > 0)
 <span class='help-block'>
     <strong>{{ "Some input field is not properly filled" }}</strong>
 </span>
    @endif
```

And works great.I want to thank to user:

> utdev

For this code:

You need to add / change following in your Controller function:

```
$request->session()->flash('success', 'Success!');
return redirect()->route("yourstuff.index");
```

In your blade.php you return that session with it message like this

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif

@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('error') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

I will use the code proposed by you in other part of my project.
THANKS !